# Modal popup with a difference

Tags: javascript, popup, window, modal-dialog

I would like to use this example of a sort of modal window as seen here: http://www.insight51.com/surf/ (just click in any image to see it in action), I checked the source of the page and I can see I will need a lot of css and scripts... this is not a normal popup...:

```
<meta name="location" content="HemiEU" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/insight/css/framework.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/insight/css/stylesheet.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/insight/css/jquery.modal.css" /> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><link href="themes/insight/css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->     
    <!--[if IE 6]><link href="themes/insight/css/ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="themes/insight/js/jquery.min.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="themes/insight/js/combined.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="themes/insight/js/common.js"></script>  
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

can you help me out?

the website I am working on is www.thedayistoday.co.uk.

Answer (score 1):

The site is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for general JavaScript sexiness, and the [jqModal plugin](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) for the modal dialog boxes. I did also notice some other jQuery plugins on the page (such as [jQuery Masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/)) but those don't really have anything to do with the modal dialogs.

Here's a very minimal demo to get you started: http://jsbin.com/aqase5

Just an FYI, there are a ***ton*** of other [jQuery modal window/lightbox plugins](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20modal%20plugin) if you want something different. A small sampling:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756342/whats-your-favorite-jquery-modal-plugin
- [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)
- [jQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)
- [DOM Window](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html)
- [Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html)
- [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

Comment: thank you so much for your reply! I now have some food for thought, I will return if I have any problems, again, cheers!